# Why returning a vector by reference is much faster than returning by move?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, c++14, move

I have two similar methods, both of which take a std::vector by reference and then one of them tries to return it by reference(since lifetime is satisfied) and another one returns by move. In both cases, I don't need the passed vector afterwards, it's just to satisfy syntactical requirement.

Both functions look like -

```
std::vector<unique_ptr<Item>> func_returns_move(std::vector<unique_ptr<Item>> &items) {
    items.erase(std::remove_if(items.begin(), items.end(),
    [&](const std::unique_ptr<Item> &item) {
        return item->age > 20;
    }), items.end());
    return move(items);
}


std::vector<unique_ptr<Item>>& func_returns_ref(std::vector<unique_ptr<Item>> &items) {
    items.erase(std::remove_if(items.begin(), items.end(),
    [&](const std::unique_ptr<Item> &item) {
        return item->age > 20;
    }), items.end());
    return items;
}
```

---

From my assumption, there shouldn't be much difference here as the only differing line is the last one - one returns by ref and another directly moves. At first I thought maybe the difference was due to move creating one temporary object which might malloc by default or something, that will be the result of function like `result = func_returns_move(...)` but it should be constant time which is not the case here. The time spent is proportional to number of elements in vector. So I'm failing to understand what is causing more execution in return by std::move case.

---

Timings are as follows -

```
FUNC_RETURNS_MOVE: 50
FUNC_RETURNS_REF: 5
```

Testing program here - https://godbolt.org/z/5Y8Mcw

Comment: Why do you even return a value?

Comment: Just a note, you shouldn't return anything with `std::move`, since the compiler will detect that it can make a move anyway, and by calling `std::move` you disable `copy-elision` that otherwise may take place, to further optimize your code.

Comment: @Lorand That's simply not true in this case. Copy elision (as in, RVO) is only performed for automatic storage duration variables (that are not function parameters), see [the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). The compiler better not move from a `T&` function parameter without my explicit request. The `std::move` usage is both correct and necessary in this code.

Comment: You can use a profile to see what happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second case, the vector is destroyed at scope exit (the only vector object is `items2`). This is outside your timed area.

In the first case however, the returned move-constructed vector temporary is destroyed at the end of the full expression, which is *within* the timed section. `items1` is still destroyed at scope exit, but it's empty at that point.

The actual time cost of both cases is essentially identical. But in the first case, the destruction of all the elements is inside the timed region, whereas in the second case it is outside.

If we keep the destruction of the returned vector object outside of the timing, we get consistent results between the two (and can see that the move is indeed "free"): https://godbolt.org/z/z-wKVG

<sup>(Due to technical licensing reasons I will not copy the relevant godbolt code here - it would need to be in the question.)</sup>

Comment: interstingly adding clearing of the vectors makes the move faster? https://godbolt.org/z/4qfvKn

Comment: What’s the footnote about licensing? Is this a reference to the recent change to CC 4.0? It honestly sounds like FUD and isn’t helpful.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It is in accordance with [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388481/mention-online-compilers-on-the-minimal-reproducible-example-page#comment722171_388545) discussion. TL;DR: Unless code posted on an external site is already under CC 4.0 (or compatible) we can't just copy it into the question (or answers) because we can't just relicense it.

Comment: @MaxLanghof You’re likely mistaken about the licensing issue. I see your point (and agree!) about the issue with just linking to Godbolt, but simply copying that trivial code wouldn’t constitute a breach of any copyright because trivial code isn’t copyrightable (see concept of Schöpfungshöhe). But ideally OP would solve this by just having *all* the relevant code in the question.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Schöpfungshöhe is a concept from German law specifically. The point of licenses is to abstract away as much of local laws and general lawyering as possible. Yes, it likely wouldn't be a breach under German copyright laws. But where is the line on that? And what does that help me if the author (or site) does not operate in Germany? I'm going to stick with the explicit guidance from meta in order to stay clear of these issues. I can move/adapt the remark from my answer to a comment on the question if you would prefer that.

Comment: @MaxLanghof The term may be specific but the concept (without a salient name, though) absolutely exists, and is universal. And this is important, because people on this site misunderstand how licensing applies, and whether e.g. trivial pieces of code fall under copyright (they absolutely, unambiguously, definitely do not). The question of what’s “trivial” ironically isn’t trivial to answer, but a lot more qualifies than what people realise.

Comment: @AlanBirtles The cause is definitely not the move, as the reverse happens when you switch the `items1` and `items2` around as parameters: https://godbolt.org/z/mHL-xQ. The same effect is visible if you completely remove the functions in question: https://godbolt.org/z/BFeKkn. Caching issue maybe?